# Is there any difference between ES6 class constructor functions and method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a difference between a constructor function vs a method like so:

```
class foo {
  constructor() {
    // A -> Function inside constructor
    this.init = () => {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }

  // B -> Method
  bar() {
    console.log('foo');
  }
}
```

I tried this on the babel REPL and tried to grok the code that it compiles but it doesn't make any sense to me ATM:

[babelREPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20foo%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Constructor%20Method%0A%20%20%20%20this.init%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('test')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Method%0A%20%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('foo')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: `bar` is defined in `foo.prototype`.

Comment: Had to answer, cause you didn't sure the ES5 example, so I am not sure if I should tell you that there is no difference or not, cause I can't compare this ES6 example to anything. 

BUT, I will say that ES6 classes are only capable of doing all the same things that Prototypes could do.